# Python smooth digital signal into analog but retain peaks

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have a pandas series of mostly zeroes with some ones, I'd like to "create tails" or "smoothen" the ones, but I'm missing the required statistics background to express what I want to google it.

Expressed as code, I have `source` and want to make it into `target`

```
source = pd.Series([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
target = pd.Series([0.0, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4])


source.plot(drawstyle="steps-pre")
target.plot(drawstyle="steps-pre")
```

Blue line is source and orange is target

[image: Blue line is source and organge is target]

How is this operation called? Bonus points for how to do it in pandas/numpy/scipy

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is exponential decay.

Comment: @MarkRansom awesome, that was just the pointer I needed! Write it as an answer and I can accept it. The convolutions are useful, but this is the solution to my problem.

Comment: I'm really curious how this is solved with exponential decay.

Comment: My comment wasn't really an answer, but I'm glad it helped you.  The numbers you used as an example don't truly match an exponential decay, although they're close.  I think the convolution answer is a perfectly good way to implement it, if you use kernel values of `[x,x**2,x**3,x**4...]` extended to the point where the multiplier no longer materially affects the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a convolution: Two functions are involved.  One is your original data, the other is called the "kernel" or "filter."  In your case the kernel is [1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1].  The result is obtained by multiplying the two together while offsetting the kernel step by step.  There are algorithms that can be more efficient than brute force, found under the general topic of "digital filtering."

Comment: Concrete code example: `target = np.convolve(source, [1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1])`.  (Some padding might be needed to adjust the lag of the spikes, if that is desired.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yeah, I'd pad the left side with zeros so that the 1.0 is in the center.